# Distribution of longest streak of consecutive (non-)birthdays in birthday problem

Tags: probability, distributions, order-statistics

Given the setting of the birthday paradox ($n$ people with birthdays randomly drawn from the uniform distribution of 365 days), let us call the days on which at least one person was born *birthdays* and all other days *non-birthdays*. What can be said about the distribution of

a) The length in days of the longest streak of birthdays;

b) The length in days of the longest streak of non-birthdays?

Is there an analytical solution to, for example, the expected value of either of these?

(You can choose whether to break all streaks when the year changes; I think insightful analysis is more interesting than the precise formulation of the problem.)

Comment: Because this question has nothing essential in common with the Birthday Paradox, I have removed that tag.  After all, it's not concerned about the chances of *collisions* in the sample--it's concerned about a completely different kind of event.

Comment: Is the year assumed to be cyclic? In other words, if you see birthdays on days 364,365,1,2 , is that a consecutive streak?

Comment: I think my formulation of the question addresses that: "You can choose whether to break all streaks when the year changes; I think insightful analysis is more interesting than the precise formulation of the problem."

Comment: A continuous version of the problem is: Observe $n$ independent uniform random variables on $(0,1)$, sort them as the order statistics $U_{(1)} < U_{(2)}< \dotsm < U_{(n)}$, compute the $n-1$ *spacings* $U_{(i)}-U_{(i-1)}$, what is the distribution of (expectation of) the largest spacing? That is answered at:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162560/distribution-of-the-largest-fragment-of-a-broken-stick-spacings