# Continuous Version of Coupon-Collector Problem

Tags: probability, distributions, coupon-collector-problem

Suppose I get in an elevator every morning and am in it for exactly one minute. A continuous loop of music plays in the elevator and is 10 minutes long.

If my daily arrival time is uniform in the time frame from 8:00 to 8:10, what is the expected number of days until I have heard the entire 10 minutes of the loop? Assume I take the stairs down at the end of the day and so am only in the elevator for one minute per day.

Comment: No - I have found a published solution, but have not had time to digest it and post.

Answer (score 8):

> This question reminds me of [Wilfrid Kendall's dead leaves
>   simulation](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/kendall/personal/abstracts/dead/), which he uses to explain the difference between
>   forward and backward sampling.

Given that the problem can be formalised through [uniform spacings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/162560/7224), this [highly detailed answer on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163147/7224) is connected with this question.

Indeed, if $U_1,\ldots,U_T$ denote the mid-times of the elevator trips on days 1, 2, ..., *T*, assumed to be Uniform on $(0,L)$, and if $U_{(1)},U_{(2)},\ldots,U_{(T)}$ are the corresponding order statistics, the condition for covering the entire L mn musical programme is
$$U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}<1,U_{(3)}-U_{(2)}<1,\ldots,U_{(T)}-U_{(T-1)}<1,$$
and
$$U_{(1)}+L-U_{(T)}<1$$
Defining the Dirichlet vector $\Delta$ associated with the spacings $U_{(i)}-U_{(i-1)}$ $(2\le i\le T+1)$, with $U_{(T+1)}=L$,
$$\Delta=\frac{1}{L}(U_{(1)},U_{(2)}-U_{(1)},
U_{(3)}-U_{(2)},\ldots,U_{(T)}-U_{(T-1)},1-U_{(T)})$$
which is Dirichlet $\mathcal{D}_{T+1}(1,\ldots,1)$, the question is thus almost equivalent to finding the law of the maximal component of $\Delta$, to determine$$\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le T+1}\Delta_i<1\big/L\right)$$for which the approximation provided in [the above mentioned answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163147/7224) applies. Obviously, this is not the entire answer to the question but it provides an interesting entry.

The expectation of $T$ can then be deduced from 
$$\mathbb{P}(\max_i\Delta_i\le 1/L) = \sum_{j=0}^{L} { T+1 \choose j } (-1)^j (1-j/L)^T,$$
since
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[T]&=\sum_{t=L+1}^\infty t \mathbb{P}(T=t)\\
&=\sum_{t=L+1}^\infty t \mathbb{P}(T\ge t)-\sum_{t=1}^\infty t \mathbb{P}(T\ge t+1)\\
&=(L+1)\mathbb{P}(T\ge L+1)+\sum_{t=L+2}^\infty \mathbb{P}(T\ge t)\\
&=(L+1)\{1-\mathbb{P}(T\le L)\}+\sum_{t=L+2}^\infty \{1-\mathbb{P}(T\le t-1)\}\\
&=L+1+\sum_{t=L+1}^\infty \{1-\mathbb{P}(T\le t)\}\\
&=L+1+\sum_{t=L+1}^\infty \left\{1-\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le T+1}\Delta_i\le1\big/L\right)\right\}\\
&=L+1+\sum_{t=L+1}^\infty \left\{1-\sum_{j=0}^{L} { t+1 \choose j } (-1)^j (1-j/L)^T\right\}\\
\end{align*}
A quick simulation shows the accuracy of the expectation

[image]

The approximation to the actual problem of "the continuous coupon collector" can also be evaluated by simulation and the regression of the simulated expected number $\hat T$ on the (approximate) expected number $\hat T_0$ shows a good fit of the formula 
$$\hat T=3/2+\hat T_0$$

[image]

Comment: So, how many days?