# Probability that any element of a random unit-length vector is large

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, sum, random-vector

Given a vector $X \in R^n = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ drawn uniformly such that:

- $x_i \in [0, 1]$ for all $i$; and
- $\sum x_i = 1$,

how would you find the probability that *any* of the $x_i > y$, for some $y \in [0, 1]$?

**Where I've gotten:**

The problem should be symmetric w.r.t. the $x$s, so the result should be equivalent to $n $ x $P(x_0 > y)$.

We can consider a process of dividing up the total interval [0, 1] into chunks. First, you choose an order to assign values to the $x$s. For example, we could say $x_4 = 0.3, x_9 = 0.1...$

In this view, $P(x_0 > y)$ = $P(x_0 > y| x_0 \text{ is chosen first})P(x_0 \text{ is chosen first}) + P(x_0 > y| x_0 \text{ is chosen second})P(x_0 \text{ is chosen second})$...

This quickly becomes a nasty recursive problem, and I'm curious if there is already an elegant solution for it, or at least a well-documented one.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the joint distribution for $\mathbf{X}$?

Comment: If $X$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere then I imagine a volume argument will work.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162560/distribution-of-the-largest-fragment-of-a-broken-stick-spacings

Comment: What do you mean by $x_i \in U(0, 1)$

Comment: Ah, my intention with $x_i \in U(0, 1)$ is to say that, marginally, the elements of the vector have a uniform distribution. I think @LarsvanderLaan's suggestion of a uniform distribution on the sphere in $R^n$ is the correct way of stating this.

Comment: @soakley This is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way I can give you credit for finding the correct answer?

Comment: Your expression for the $L^1$ norm is incorrect, so which do you intend: that the $x_i$ sum to unity (as written) or that their *absolute values* sum to unity (as implied by use of the norm)?  Could you clarify that by "sphere" you mean the $L^1$ sphere and not the (usual) $L^2$ sphere?  Previous comments and edits strongly suggest your statement of this problem is not the one you intend.

Comment: @whuber thanks for keeping me honest! I wasn't being careful with my writing. Fixing now.

Comment: There's still an ambiguity.  Are you trying to say that $x$ is uniform on the unit simplex or that its distribution is conditional on the sum of *iid* uniform components lying on the simplex?  The two distributions are not the same and the answer will be different, too.